# Erro ao integrar Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 + JPA 2 e Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, glassfish, spring-jpa

Não estou conseguindo iniciar a transação do Spring, é alguma configuração que fiz errado quem poder me ajudar. segue os códigos:

```html
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:382)
 at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy221.list(Unknown Source)
 at com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controller.BookController.list(BookController.java:41)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

persistence.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="LOCAL_PERSISTENCE"  transaction-type="JTA">
  <description> Spring Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/_scdweb</jta-data-source>
  <class>com.boraji.tutorial.spring.model.Book</class>
  <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
  </properties>

 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->
```

AppConfig.java

```html
package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring.dao"),
      @ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring.service") })
public class AppConfig {

   @Bean
   public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean geEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
      LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("LOCAL_PERSISTENCE");
      return factoryBean;
   }
  

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
        = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
              geEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );
      return transactionManager;
   }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```html
package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

MyWebAppInitializer.java

```html
package com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vamos ver se posso lhe ajudar.

1. substitua o persistence.xml por um arquivo de configuração.
2. crie o repositorio como interface expandindo JpaRepository

> ```
> @Repository
> public interface Cervejas extends JpaRepository<ClasseJpa, TipoChaveId>{
> }
> ```

3. Na Classe de Serviço anote o método com @Transactional do org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

   Caso seja do seu interesse tem no meu github um projeto que fiz no curso da algaworks com esses conceitos.
   https://github.com/marcelosartor/curso-spring-mvc-expert

Alias, não sei o seu nivel de conhecimento em spring mas esse curso da algawoks é muito bom, recomendo.